# Is there a possibility to pause a thread until Scanner class detects input?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a small chat program.

This is the important part of my server class so far, which starts a thread to listen to client input:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

while (true) {
    if ( in .hasNextLine() && clientName == null) {
        clientName = in .nextLine();
    }
    if ( in .hasNextLine()) {
        String input = in .nextLine();
        out.println(clientName + ":  " + input);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

However, this is constantly looping. I want it to wait for the input, and pause the thread until this happens. Is there a built in function for Scanner to wait for a next line, instead of checking if there is one and then returning true of false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `hasNextLine` call, and `nextLine` will block.